# Android Popup window behavior

Tags: android

In Android, While using Popup window

If I use `setBackgroundDrawable` property to popup window
Then:

```
  // Back button cannot override
  // Outside touch working
```

If I doesn't use `setBackgroundBrawable` property to popup window
Then:

```
  // Back button can override
  // Outside touch is not working
```

What should I do if I want both events at a same time ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Hi,

Here is my piece of code



if (mBackground == null) 
 mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources()));
else 
 mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackground);

mWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mWindow.setTouchable(true);
mWindow.setFocusable(true);
mWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
mWindow.setContentView(mRootView);
mWindow.getContentView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Comment: in the future please edit your question when you want to add code. Do not put it in the commments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
myPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Comment: Hi,

Here is my piece of code



if (mBackground == null) 
 mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources()));
else 
 mWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(mBackground);

mWindow.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
mWindow.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
mWindow.setTouchable(true);
mWindow.setFocusable(true);
mWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
mWindow.setContentView(mRootView);
mWindow.getContentView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to set as mContext.getResources() in the setbackgroundDrawable if your mbackGround is null? try to set it like this   `mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_menu)`

Comment: Hi,

I have popupwindow with custom UI and it contains some check boxes. I am able to display this popup. I have my business logic here, when I am pressing back button I need to check any one check box is selected or not, If not then I don't want to dismiss popup window (in short need to override back press). This is achieved by not using setBgDrawable property to popup.
But with back button overidding, I need to dismiss popup on outside touch.Problem is when I am not setting setBgDrawable property (to override back press) it kills touch event and I need both these.

Answer (score 0):

When you use PopWindow your Activity doesn't have focus anymore, that's why neither onBackPressed nor onTouchEvent work, but if you set it's focus `yourPopupWindow.setFocusable(false);` your activity will still have focus and you'll be able to perform touch and back on it.